# Where is the Persistence tool window in Intellij IDEA 15?

Tags: intellij-idea, persistence

I want to generate model Class from mysql database, but I cannot find the persistence tool window which is easily searched in IDEA 14.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The persistence support is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (and not in the Community Edition, I think). When you create a new project in for example [IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP) (build 143.1453.5), the New Project dialog opens:

[image: New Project dialog]

There you can for example select "Java Enterprise" in the left panel and "JavaEE Persistence (2.0)" in the "Additional Libraries and Frameworks" list. Now the Persistence panel can be opened via the View | Tool Windows | Persistence menu. The Persistence panel is visible here in the bottom left part:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA with persistence panel]

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: if you want to add JavaEE Persistence to your project later, you can follow the advice from [Mr D](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2180290/mr-d): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36052050/1694043.

Answer (score 28):

If you haven't included JavaEE Persistance when you created your project as [@Freek de Bruijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694043/freek-de-bruijn) suggested, you can go into:

```
File - > Project Structure - > Modules -> + -> "JPA"
```

That will enable `persistence` under `Tool windows` as well if, like me, you checked out your project from version control. Took me quite a bit of time to find that setting actually.

Comment: Well hidden feature.

Answer (score 6):

Echoing what @0x6C38 said here.
File-> Project Structure -> Modules -> + then type in JPA.

[image]

Then you will have it in the Tool Windows.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the persistence tool window is not visible then maybe it will help to add the Framework Support with this:

In the project window. Right click at the name then 'Add Framework Support...'

Enable here the JPA support.